# Why does this array_walk function throw an error?

Tags: php

```
array_walk ($this->something, [$this, 'function_name'], $part_something);
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /.../...php on line 67

This works on my local test environment, but not on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running PHP 5.4 in production? If not the bracket syntax is not a valid way to represent an array in PHP 5.3 and below as it is a new feature in 5.4.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
array_walk ($this->something, array($this, 'function_name'), $part_something);
```

Look at this https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Comment: class method name: array_walk($this->something, array($this, 'function_name'), $part_something);

Comment: Yes, correct... I realized only now that you are calling a method of the same class.