# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, syntax

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in **$results = [];**

```
function class_uses_recursive($class)
{
    $results = [];

    foreach (array_merge([$class => $class], class_parents($class)) as $class)
    {
        $results += trait_uses_recursive($class);
    }

    return array_unique($results);
}
```

please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this array\_walk function throw an error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845574/why-does-this-array-walk-function-throw-an-error)

Comment: What did you try to fix the problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're using an older version of PHP (pre-5.4 I think), this syntax isn't supported:

```
$results = [];
```

You'd have to use the older version:

```
$results = array();
```

Comment: Did they remove it again in 7.3? I got the same error in PHP 7.3 and was able to fix it by replacing [] with array()

Answer (score 2):

You will get this error for any PHP version below 5.4, as the short array syntax `[]` was not introduced until 5.4. You need to use `array()` to instantiate arrays in PHP 5.3.x and earlier:

```
function class_uses_recursive($class)
{
    $results = array();

    foreach (array_merge(array($class => $class), class_parents($class)) as $class)
    {
        $results += trait_uses_recursive($class);
    }

    return array_unique($results);
}
```

PHP docs on arrays [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 0):

Array is initialised by

```
$results = array(); // use this


 function class_uses_recursive($class)
    {
        $results = []; //instead of this .

        foreach (array_merge([$class => $class], class_parents($class)) as $class)
        {
            $results += trait_uses_recursive($class);
        }

        return array_unique($results);
    }
```